# Display Data In DataTable For Logged In User

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have been trying to research this for a while now, but haven't been able to find a good example to check out. What I would like to accomplish is to have my DataTable display only data relevant to the user that is currently logged in (and then have an admin account that can see everything). I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 with Windows Authentication which doesn't have a traditional login screen built into it (it just does that quick check and logs in the user). The application is connected to an SQL database. The way that I would have done it in the past is have the user log in using a login screen, store their information into a session variable, and then work off of that. Is something similar to that possible with DataTables?

Here is my html:

```
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jszip-2.5.0,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script> 
</head>

<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin: 10px; padding: 5px;">Start Date:</td>
            <td><input name="min" id="min" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin: 10px; padding: 5px;">End Date:</td>
            <td><input name="max" id="max" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table width="100%" class="display" id="reportTable" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/total.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/daterange.js"></script>
```

Here is a fiddle of my DataTable:
https://jsfiddle.net/l337method/hfyo90w7/

Comment: When you query the data use where condition/method to get data only for that specific user(current user)

Comment: That could be an excellent way of going about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your DataTable populate from an AJAX source and set up your Web API to display the data that's relevant for the currently logged in user.

Create a Web API controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/employees")]
public IEnumerable<Employees> GetEmployeesByLoggedInUser()
{
  var user = User.Identity.Name;  // <-- Username of the currently logged in user.
  // get the resource by this user
  var employees = repo.GetEmployeesByUser(user); 
  return employees;
}
```

Then initialize your DataTable this way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/employees',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#yourTableId").dataTable({
                data: data,
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: 'name'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'position'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'office'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'age'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'salary'
                    }]
            });
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  I will look into it.  Thank you for the response!